# How do I adjust settings on Afloat for the Mac?

Tags: mac, afloat

I'm using Afloat to give me the "always on top" feature on every application window.

I can't find Afloat's settings.

I can see in the Window menus of my other programs, but I can't find its app or its settings.

Comment: Is it possible that [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) does not have any settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really are no preferences. I checked the installer bundle and there really is nothing in it except the SIMBL installer and SIMBL bundle providing menu items, so no System Preferences pane or standalone management application. And since there's no menu item for configuration provided by the bundle, there's really nothing else. The documentation doesn't mention any preferences or configuration either.

I have an ancient preferences file (from 2007) on my system, `~/Library/Preferences/org.altervista.millenomi.Afloat.plist`, but it only contains whether I accepted its license.

---

If you want to customize the keyboard shortcuts, you can do so in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This response is more thorough than I imagined I could get from anyone but the developers of the app. Thanks!

Comment: My Keyboard settings does not show the afloat options here :(

Comment: @StevenLu That's because you need to add it. Click the plus button.

Comment: They should really add an entry automatically. Anyway, I've set mine to Ctrl+Cmd+A (to match the Ctrl+Cmd scroll to adjust opacity), and it's perfect.